# Failed to instantiate instance of destination [AbstractClass] error in ModelMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance, modelmapper

I have Abstract class `Room`:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "room_type")
@Data
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Room {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "room_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private int roomId;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 255)
private String name;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
private List<Workstation> workstationsList;
}
```

I also have some concrete classes that extends from `Room`.
In my `Workstation` class i have `One to one` relationship with `Room`:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Workstation {
@Id
@Column(name = "workstation_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private int workstationId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
private Room room;
}
```

I am using `ModelMaper` to map `WorkstationDTO` to `Workstation` entity but i am getting `Failed to instantiate instance of destination com.entity.Room. Ensure that com.entity.Room has a non-private no-argument constructor.` which is probably because `Room` is abstract class, is there a way to solve this without removing abstract keyword in `Room` entity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is because an abstract class cannot (nor interfaces) be instantiated.  You could use a converter but to instantiate a concrete class you need to know what is its the actual type:

```
var roomConverter = new Converter<RoomDto, Room>() {
    // inner mapper to avoid any side effects
    private final ModelMapper innerMapper = new ModelMapper();

    @Override
    public Room convert(MappingContext<RoomDto, Room> context) {
        // If your RoomDto had the type as field you could determine the actual type to
        // instantiate, so one of the possible many RoomImpl.
        return innerMapper.map(context.getSource(), RoomImpl.class);
    }
};

// Create the type map and register converter
modelMapper.createTypeMap(RoomDto.class, Room.class).setConverter(roomConverter);
```

Now adding field, for example:

```
@Getter
private Class<Room> classOfRoom;
```

it could be use in method `convert(..)` to instantiate the correct implementation.